# postgres - "generic max" based on value's data type

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I'm trying to come up with a postgreSQL snippet which all agg any value by its type.

example:

```sql
with ni2 as (
 select 1 as id_, TRUE as chid
 UNION ALL select 2 as id_, FALSE as chid
 UNION ALL select 3 as id_, NULL as chid
)
SELECT
  (CASE when pg_typeof(chid)::text != 'boolean' then max(chid)
   else bool_or(chid)
  end) as generic_max
FROM
  ni2
```

my question is - why does still fail?
I'm getting something like:

```
db error: ERROR: function max(boolean) does not exist HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The idea here is dynamically choose the right agg function based on the value data type so, ideally I would not care what the data type of the value being aggregated.

Comment: It makes no sense to test the data type for every row as it's bound to be the same type within the same query. What's the actual input to your query? A table? And can the output be type `text` regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Expression Evaluation Rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL):

> Another limitation of the same kind is that a CASE cannot prevent evaluation of an aggregate expression contained within it, because aggregate expressions are computed before other expressions in a SELECT list or HAVING clause are considered. For example, the following query can cause a division-by-zero error despite seemingly having protected against it:

> SELECT CASE WHEN min(employees) > 0
> THEN avg(expenses / employees)
> END
> FROM departments;

> The min() and avg() aggregates are computed concurrently over all the input rows, so if any row has employees equal to zero, the division-by-zero error will occur before there is any opportunity to test the result of min(). Instead, use a WHERE or FILTER clause to prevent problematic input rows from reaching an aggregate function in the first place.

I would recommend reading that entire section of the docs.